# Compiling conditionally inserted html in an ng-repeat which is within a directive's template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got a directive's template with an ng-repeat directive which looks like this:

```
template: "<table ng-repeat='num in seq track by $index'><tr><td>{{$index+1}}</td><td>{{num}}</td></tr></table>"
```

$scope.seq is an array of numbers, up until index 131, at which point I pushed the string `"<span class='stayTuned'>stay tuned!</span>"`.

Of course, this string is pushed as is and is not a DOM element.  What is the best way to compile this html string into a DOM element and then "append" it, but within the context of my list?

Comment: What do you mean by `at which point I push the string` where are pushing the string?

Comment: I dont see the code for pushing the string, can you share that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I understand your question, if I were to rephrase:

> How do I create a list with ng-repeat, and *only* if the number of list elements exceeds 131, append`<span>`?

If this is so, you don't need anything fancy to $compile - just use existing Angular's directives - `ng-if` and filters - `limitTo` - in your template.

**Template** (multi-line for readability):

```
<table ng-repeat='num in seq | limitTo: 131 track by $index'>
  <tr>
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{num}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<span ng-if="seq.length > 131" class='stayTuned'>stay tuned!</span>
```

Comment: Oh gosh, I re-read back over my question, now hours later and I can see how unclear I was with my question.  I appreciate you rephrasing it very close to how i meant it and answering.